# Invalid value for <circle> attribute r="NaN" in D3 scatterplot code

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am getting a NaN error on the r value in a d3 scatterplot.

Console error: Error: Invalid value for  attribute r="NaN"

From this section of the code:

`g.selectAll(".response")
            .attr("r", function(d){
                return responseScale(d.responses);
            })
            .attr("cx", function(d){
                return x(d.age);
            })
            .attr("cy", function(d){
                return y(d.value);
            })`

Here is how the scale is set up:

```
var responseScale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){
    return d.responses;
}))
.range(2, 15);
```

Here is a sample of the data:

```
var data = [
{glazed: 3.14, jelly: 4.43, powdered: 2.43, sprinkles: 3.86, age: 18, responses: 7},
{glazed: 3.00, jelly: 3.67, powdered: 2.67, sprinkles: 4.00, age: 19, responses: 3},
{glazed: 2.00, jelly: 4.00, powdered: 2.33, sprinkles: 4.33, age: 20, responses: 3},
```

I have tried putting a plus sign in front of d.responses and using parseFloat().

The code is an example used in this course, [Learning to Visualize Data with D3.js](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-to-visualize/9781771373043/) (chapter on Creating a Scatterplot)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code:

```
var responseScale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){
    return d.responses;
}))
.range(2, 15);
```

The parameter for the range() function should be an array of values, like this: .range([2,15]);

corrected scale:

```
 var responseScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){
        return d.responses;
    }))
    .range([2, 15])
```

;

More info on scales can be found [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales). If you are still in trouble, let me know!

Comment: If the answer is correct, can you please accept it? Thank you :-)